# selenium firefox css selector crash

Tags: css, firefox, selenium, crash

i use ubuntu 12 and selenium and firefox 7 (first is 21 ,i checked selenium support list,it doesnot support firefox 21, so i uninstall 21 and install 7. i also install selenium ide and selenium webdriver.

here is my target

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="vd_dload" data-info="....">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="vd_dload" data-info="....">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="vd_dload" data-info="....">
```

so i use eq(0) eq(1) to select the element. i test it in selenium ide, it works. i select it like

```
 command  clickandwait css=a.vd_dload:eq(2)
```

and save as python test code

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.vd_dload:eq(1)").click()
```

and the python code cashes here. it report:

```
InvalidSelectorException:Message: u'The give selecor a.vd_dload:eq(2) is either invalid or does not result in a webElement. the following error occurred:\n[Exception.."An invalid or illegal string was specified" code:"12" nsresult:"0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)" location......
```

anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eq` is a jQuery selector, and thus not part of the CSS standard. Therefore, once you run it with Selenium telling it "here's my CSS selector", it's going to be a very unhappy tool.

Although not a **direct equivalent** (as in, `eq` != `nth-child`), in your instance, the CSS selector `nth-child` is going to work fine:

```
a.vd_dload:nth-child(1)
a.vd_dload:nth-child(2)
a.vd_dload:nth-child(3)
```

Note, `nth-child` CSS selector is part of the CSS3 selector spec, thus may cause problems with IE. It is only supported in IE9 and above, and any modern version of FF/Chrome/etc.

Comment: now it does not report that "An invalid or illegal string was specified", it reports "element is not current visable and so may not be interactive with" but i am pretty sure the css selector is right. and i have tried use xpath,doesn't work too.

Comment: That is a slightly different problem. I'd say create a new question for that.